# Shaping outgoing traffic with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, qos

On my laptop, when I run any downloads, torrents, etc, browsing is crippled.

I read somewhere that you could configure your [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/) powered router to prioritize certain network traffic.

Could I do the same on my pc for all network traffic? I would like to prioritize packets in the following order:

1. SSH
2. Gaming
3. Browsing
4. Chat
5. Downloads/Torrents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Linux kernel has the ability to do traffic shaping / QoS which can be set up using the `tc(8)` command (not `iptables`). The full details are too much to go in to an answer here, but as a first step you may want to look at the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://lartc.org/) howto.

There are also a number of applications that build on the `tc` command to allow you to more easily define shaping rules such as *wondershaper* or as part of a firewall system such as *shorewall*.